# Рекурсивное нытьё

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток, нытьё

Метка [нытье](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b5) неправильно синонимизирована. Главный вариант [нытье](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b5), а должен быть [нытьё](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%91).

Переделайте синоним в другую сторону. Ну передеееееелайте. =)

Comment: Не п̶л̶а̶ч̶ь̶ ̶ ной, д̶е̶в̶ч̶о̶н̶к̶а̶ ТС, пройдут дожди, с̶о̶л̶д̶а̶т̶ ̶в̶е̶р̶н̶ё̶т̶с̶я̶ синоним изменится,ты только жди!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю перестать синонимизировать метки запросами на мете и начать использовать стандартный механизм с голосованием за синонимы.

Comment: Когда уже установлен синоним, нельзя обратно повернуть. А вообще — да, на мете стоит только призывать к голосованию, но не к прямым действиям модератора.

Comment: @NickVolynkin нытье стоит вообще удалить, imo

Comment: @PashaPash, и не надейтесь.

Comment: @Nofate буду [tag:Ныть] пока не удалят

Comment: Что? Удалить нытье [tag:нытье]? Нет пути. Это же единственный кусочек того самого теплого-лампового Хэшкода, в котором не посылали в гугл и можно было спрашивать что лучше A или B? Нужно наоборот еще добавить метку [tag:раньшебылолучше]

Comment: @igumnov получите [заряд ностальгии](https://web.archive.org/web/20131230203737/http://hashcode.ru/)!

Comment: @igumnov, странно. На моем хэшкоде сплошь и рядом слали в гугл. Устал удалять уже. Сейчас меньше шлют.

Comment: @Nofate На самом деле это была просто ностальгия, я бы и сейчас с удовольствием послал кого-нибудь в Google. Привет ТС, иди н̶а̶ ̶в Google.